# Monad Transformer naming conventions

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

Whenever I combine `Future` and `Either` (or any other close variants) through `EitherT`, I use abstract yet descriptive enough name like `Task`.

But since naming stuff out of thin air is [one of the few challenges](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) in programming, I'd much prefer to have some solid naming conventions that I can follow instead.

For example, how would we name a monad of `State` and `Either` using `StateT`? :

```
type ???[E, S, A] = StateT[Either[E, ?], S, A]
```

Is there any solid naming convention that I can follow or is coming up with abstract names like `Task` better suited (given that such monad will be used repeatedly throughout the code)?

Comment: I think one common thing for quite specialized stacks is to name them after the domain you're using it later, e.g. calling a `ReaderT Config (ErrorT GameError (State GameState))` your `GameMonad`, or something like that (this is also done in Real World Haskell [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html)).

Comment: @phg What if the monad needs to be general and used throughout?

Comment: Well, then I just don't know of any conventions ;) I guess that combined transformers are almost always already specialized enough to be named after "what they are". For example, monadic parsers are in principle just "StateT s (Error e) a", although we usually call them "Parser s e a" or the like. Really, I don't think there's an answer to this question.

Comment: @phg Hmmm okay. I guess I need to think through my abstraction a little more. Perhaps I'm using wrong level of abstraction and thus the awkward naming. Thanks for your help :)